Django Custom Database Backend
I am trying to use a third party database backend and to understand the topic I followed the approach described under this link: https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-custom-django-database-backends-a-comprehensive-guide-for-developers-c8fb7e6a49ed
So I used a docker instance of python:latest  (3.13.0) and installed django (5.1.13).
I followed the article

Complete Real-World Demo: Creating and Using a Custom Django Database
Backend

in the article above. When I reached the migration part, I received the error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_backend.base.base'; 'custom_backend.base' is not a package

So I changed the settings to:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'custom_backend',  # .base removed
        'NAME': 'my_custom_db',
        'USER': 'custom_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'custom_password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

I still get an error:


File "/project/custom_backend_project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
    ~~~~^^
  File "/project/custom_backend_project/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/importlib/__init__.py", line 88, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1022, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 40, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    ...<123 lines>...
            )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 143, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 231, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 194, in create_connection
    return backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 114, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable



The structure of the project is shown here:


lets see it, issue seems to be with your custom backend's structure. Check that custom_backend and its subfolders have __init__.py files to make them proper Python packages. In your DATABASES config, set 'ENGINE': 'custom_backend.base' if DatabaseWrapper is in base.py.
Also, ensure DatabaseWrapper properly defines required attributes like client_class and methods like get_new_connection. Test importing your backend (from custom_backend.base import DatabaseWrapper) to catch any path issues.
For details, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/custom-db-backend/. let me knw if it works.

Hi Jack, the document "how-to" link does not work.

Hi Jack, I have added the project structure in my initial post. I tried the Engine setting with 'custom_backend.base' and there was the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_backend.base.base'. That was the reason why I deleted the ".base". Also the documentation link says to omit the ".base":  DATABASES = {     "default": {         "ENGINE": "mydbengine",         # ...     }, }
